# JQM: popup not closing on timeout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, setinterval, jquery-mobile-popup

I have managed to get a popup to open on page load, but only the first time that page is opened. Once it opens, I want it to close on its own after several seconds, but I am not able to do that.

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(document).on('pageshow', function (event) {
if (sessionStorage.popUpShown != 'true') {

    $('#strelica').popup('open', {positionTo: '#hitnizbor'});

    sessionStorage.popUpShown = 'true';
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#strelica").popup("close");
    }, 3000);
}

else{
    alert('already shown the popup');
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider putting the setTimeout outside of the condition, just under on('pagesshow'... line

Answer (score 3):

Your example should work, but I made you a safer version: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Uauar/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){     
    var start = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#strelica').popup('open', {positionTo: '#hitnizbor'});
        clearInterval(start);
    }, 0);    

    var stop = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#strelica").popup("close");
        clearInterval(stop);        
    }, 3000);
});
```

This code can be used in every page event, not only pageshow. If you want it to be executed only once use pageinit.

ClearInterval is here to prevent constant opening and closing. If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However it opens the popup again when I navigate back to index from external page. That is why I was using sessionStorage before. How do I make it work with your code?

Comment: If this external page is still part of your project and you have didn't prevented classic page loading with an ajax then you can simply use pageinit instead of pageshow. In any other case stich with sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery plugin? I found the answer in jquery plugin popupjs:

```
$('a.popup').popup({
   afterOpen : function(){
     var popup = this;
     setTimeout(function(){
        popup.close();
    }, 2000);
}
});
```

It is possible you miss the official sample.

Comment: Look at the tags, he is using jQuery mobile.